# Filamanaging limited to Cpanel Filemanager?

Tags: html, cpanel, file-manager

I am renting hosting (and URL) from a company (hostgator) which gives me cpanel as my default way of entering the website.

Am i limited to using the Cpanel File Manager in browser to sort my files?

Is there another way. For example  linking a physical folder on my desktop to a file manager folder (inwhich they automatically update filemanager when i edit the folder in windows?). If other forms exist how safe are they for the health of my desktop and the files on my server?

My issue is i really dont think filemanager in cpanel is a very good user experience (viewing, sorting etc).

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your Web Disk Account to mange your all file from your computer, mobile device etc. Here are the some useful cPanel doc of web disk.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Web+Disk